# Hack CSS para funcionar somente no Internet Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Em outros navegadores está com o alinhamento correto, porém fui efetuar o teste no internet explorer do windows 10 e está com uma quebra no layout, estou tentando utilizar o hack abaixo, porém não quer funcionar.

```
/* Internet Explorer 10+, Microsoft Edge Browser */

_: - ms-lang (x), #AbasCheckup ul > li > a {padding: 5px 26px 5px 26px; }
```

Comment: Fernando editei minha resposta com duas opções de formatação do CSS, ambas funcionaram para mim no Windows10 e no Edge 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onde vc escreveu

`_: - ms-lang (x), ...`

Deveria estar com o **-** colado no **ms-** dessa forma:

`_: -ms-lang (x), ...`

Para usar o CSS conforme na sua pergunta e funcionar tem que ser dessa forma: (no Edge 15 funcionou sem problemas)

```
<style>
_:-ms-lang(x), _:-webkit-full-screen, #AbasCheckup ul > li > a {padding: 5px 26px 5px 26px; }
</style>
```

Outra forma que testei e também funciona do Edge 12 para cima, pelo menos até o 15 sei que funciona!:

```
<style>
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
    #AbasCheckup ul > li > a { padding: 5px 26px 5px 26px; } 
}
</style>
```

Aqui tem mais uma listá com várias opções para o Edge: https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/css-hacks-for-windows-10-and-spartan-browser-preview/

Comment: Me perdoe pela demora para responder, muito obrigado pelas respostas utilizei essa: @supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) { e funcionou tudo certinho!

Comment: @Fernando que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marcar a Resposta com "Aceita" `✔`