# Mudar css quando o site for aberto no ie/edge

Tags: html, css

Fiz uma nova página pra um site e estou com problemas quanto a visualização dessa página no ie/edge. (basicamente é só o margin-left de um elemento)

Pela pesquisa que fiz não tem como mais carregar um css especifico se for identificado que o browser é ie/edge.

Tentei utilizar o hack css, mas não entendi como funciona.

Já testei a pagina na maioria dos navegadores e funciona perfeitamente, e como sempre só o ie da problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Encontrei estes posts que talvez possam te ajudar:**

- [problemas-com-layout-e-css-em-ie-10-e-11](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275805/problemas-com-layout-e-css-em-ie-10-e-11/275956#275956)
- [hack-css-para-funcionar-somente-no-internet-edge](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269818/hack-css-para-funcionar-somente-no-internet-edge)
- [how-to-write-a-css-hack-for-ie-11? *(post em inglês)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541306/how-to-write-a-css-hack-for-ie-11?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [get-ie8-conditional-style-sheet-for-responsive-web-design-to-work *(post em inglês)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611343/get-ie8-conditional-style-sheet-for-responsive-web-design-to-work/21621375#21621375)
- [put-browser-specific-condition-in-css-selector *(post em inglês*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291985/put-browser-specific-condition-in-css-selector)

Veja agora algumas das possíveis soluções descritas nas referências. É importante que você procure saber como funcionam esses hacks, de onde vêm e como ou porquê utilizá-los, ou seja, em quais situações seria apropriado seu uso.

**Exemplo que pode ser utilizado para corrigir problemas de layout no IE10/11**

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
   /* IE10+ specific styles go here */

}
```

Alguns hacks para IE e Microsoft Edge Windows 10

**IE 6**

```
* html .ie6 {property:value;}
```

**IE 7**

```
*+html .ie7 {property:value;}
```

**IE 6 e 7**

```
@media screen\9 {
.ie67 {property:value;}
}
```

ou

```
.ie67 { *property:value;}
```

**IE 6, 7 e 8**

```
@media \0screen\,screen\9 {
.ie678 {property:value;}
}
```

**IE 8**

```
html>/**/body .ie8 {property:value;}
```

ou

```
@media \0screen {
    .ie8 {property:value;}
}
```

**IE 8, 9 e 10**

```
@media screen\0 {
.ie8910 {property:value;}
}
```

**IE 10**

```
_:-ms-lang(x), .ie10 { property:value\9; }
```

**Edge**

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
  .selector { property:value; } 
}
```

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/165317)

Comment: Ah sim! Obrigado. Vou fazê-lo.

Comment: Consegui resolver. Com a sua ajuda e mais algumas alterações no código. Vlw :)

Comment: Que bom. Fico feliz em ter ajudado.